# Prove that something is the general solution of something.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $\alpha e^{\lambda t}  $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ + \beta e^{\lambda t} $$\begin{pmatrix}t\\1\end{pmatrix}$$   $  is the general solution of 
$X' = $$\begin{pmatrix} {\lambda}&1\\0&{\lambda}\end{pmatrix}$$ X. $

My approach is first start with:
$X'= $$\alpha {\lambda}e^{\lambda t}  $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ + \beta {\lambda} e^{\lambda t} $$\begin{pmatrix}t\\1\end{pmatrix}$$   $

however, since i take the derivative respect to t, i am wondering do i need to take the derivative with respect to the t in one of the entry of the vector. if so, how could i do it?

Thank you

Comment: Yes you need to take the derivative of $\begin{pmatrix}t\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do, and it might be easier to see how/why in the following way. Really, the solution you've defined a function

$$
f(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha e^{\lambda t} + \beta t e^{\lambda t}\\ \beta e^{\lambda t}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}(\alpha + \beta t)e^{\lambda t}\\ \beta e^{\lambda t}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By definition, the derivative of a matrix of functions $g(t) = (a_{i,j}(t))$ is the matrix of derivatives $g'(t) = (a_{i,j}'(t))$. So you need to differentiate each entry of the matrix on the RHS:

$$
f'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{d}{dt}((\alpha + \beta t)e^{\lambda t})\\ \frac{d}{dt}(\beta e^{\lambda t})\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Alternatively, you can just compute the derivative without combining the vectors first by using the product rule. Do you see how?